# Block use of arrow keys in read only columns in gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using VS 2005,asp.net,c#.net.
I have a grid view which is in an update panel.
Is it possible to block the moving of arrow keys to readonly columns in gridview

Thanks in advance
George.

Answer (score 0):

Write a JavaScript function that will be called on when the event KeyDown fires. The check, if the keycode (member of eventArgs) equals the code of an arrow key. If so, skip the column or just return, if you want to do nothing.

edit:

something like this:

```
function skipKeyPress(event){
  // 37 = left arrow key
  // 38 = up arrow key
  // 39 = right arrow key
  // 40 = down arrow key
  if(event.keyCode >= 37 && event.keyCode <=40)
    return;
}
```

Comment: Hi Chrisi, My requirement is like this, the focus should go to one editable cell to next editable cell in the gridview when pressing right arrow keys.That mean the focus should never come to columnns with tabindex=-1 and readonly when pressing arrow keys

Comment: in that case, perform some other action instead of the return statement. I dont know, how you implemented your focus functionality, but i asume that its done by some JavaScript function sincs it has to happen on client side.